# How to write CURL under vb 10

Tags: vb.net, curl

```
@ECHO OFF

curl -v -X GET "https://mydata-dev.azure-api.net/RequestInvoices?mark={string}&nextPartitionKey={string}&nextRowKey={string}"
-H "aade-user-id: "
-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {subscription key}"

--data-ascii "{body}"
```

How to write this under Visual Basic 2010 ?

Comment: Are you aware of [Azure for .NET and .NET Core developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/)?

Comment: What research have you done so far? It's important to include this information when asking a question on SO.

Comment: Net Core developers

Comment: That's not saying much...  (BTW, to address a specific person in the comments, you'll want to @mention him so that he receives a notification. This isn't necessary, however, when your intended recipient is the author of the Q or the A.)

Comment: FYI https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

As @AndrewMorton indicated, you might consider using the .NET Azure API instead. If that's not an option, however, you can use the `WebClient` class to do this.

```
Imports System.Net

Friend Module Main
  Public Sub Main()
    Dim sResponse as String

    Using oRequest As New WebClient
      oRequest.QueryString.Add("mark", "{String}")
      oRequest.QueryString.Add("nextPartitionKey", "{String}")
      oRequest.QueryString.Add("nextRowKey", "{String}")

      oRequest.Headers.Remove("aade-user-id")
      oRequest.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim - Subscription - Key", "{subscription key}")

      sResponse = oRequest.DownloadString("https://mydata-dev.azure-api.net/RequestInvoices")
    End Using
  End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: That give error at "oRequest.Headers.Remove('aade-user-id')"

Comment: What is the error? It's important to provide as much detail as possible. It appears from your `curl` request that you're attempting to remove the header: `Remove an internal header by giving a replacement without content on the right side of the colon, as in: -H "Host:"` (https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)

Comment: HResult -2147024809 {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}

Comment: @TachlampourisGeorge ~ Are you trying to remove the header in your `curl` request?

Comment: @TachlampourisGeorge ~ Step through the code and examine the contents of the Headers property. If `aade-user-id` doesn't exist as a default header, you may remove that line of code.

Comment: That fix the problem oRequest.Headers.Add("aade-user-id", Userid) oRequest.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", KeyIdOK)